# rails - how can I upgrade my jquery, I don't see it in app/assets but it's referenced in application.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, assets

Due to this bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921

I need to upgrade my jquery-ui

When I look in development at app/assets/javascripts I see this:

but no jquery-ui

Nothing in public as we don't compile assets in development.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` has this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// Comment about stuff
//= require jquery-ui
//= require LISA
//= require jquery.rest
//= require jquery.autoSuggest.packed
```

Ruby `1.9.3-p194`, `rails 3.2.8` (being upgraded from `rails 3.2.6`)

[image]

Comment: is there any gem you are using like `jquery-rails` or something

Comment: yes the gem is jquery-rails.  does that mean jquery-ui and if so how can I bump the version.

Comment: I don't believe that `jquery-rails` includes jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check `lib/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/javascripts` too?

Really, it should be in the `vendor` folder. It is a "vendored" jQuery plugin because a 3rd party authored it.

Also, as @Amar mentioned in his comment, it could also be installed via a gem.

Comment: Good thought.  However lib/assets is empty.

Comment: Ah, but vendor/assets/javascripts has it!

Comment: so it looks like that's the place where I'll put my (downloaded) new version of jquery-ui then?

Comment: Right. I updated my answer to include information about what the `vendor` folder is for.

Comment: Instead of downloading jQuery to `vendor/assets`, you can also just include it from a CDN like Google's https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery. There are some potential benefits to doing so, primarily that since many sites do this, visitors are likely to already have a cached copy of the library.